# Eclipse: How to get more space in front of line number

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way I can get some more space in front of my line numbers? Right now they are right next the side the frame with no space.

I tried going to preference, but I can only find (turn on/off) option. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I've given to your question a +1 plus half an hour of my life George but I really couldn't find a solution. Honestly I never saw anybody willing to edit that piece of GUI.

Comment: Not a answer to ur question,but I really want 2 know that what is your font setting for this color theme?tks :-)

Comment: @SamSu It is Obsidian created by Morinar. You can download it here: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=21.

Comment: @George Yes I know the name of this theme.But I asked u the about `font` name...

Comment: @SamSu Ohh! It is `Monaco` under the English Collection. Size 11.

Comment: If `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn` is responsible for drawing them, it looks baked in. See `computeIndentations()`  in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.jface/text/3.7.0/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/LineNumberRulerColumn.java#LineNumberRulerColumn.computeIndentations%28%29